# Sourcing bash script, how don't display the output?

Tags: bash

I have two scripts, the 'main' script, script A and a script B which contains some variables. In script A, I include script B for use the variable defined in the script B like so:

scriptA:

```
. ./scriptb
...
echo $toto
```

scriptB:

```
export toto="hello !"
```

When I run my script A, I get the output:

```
$./scriptA
/home/user/scriptb
hello !
```

My question is how to remove the undesired `/home/user/scriptb` from output.

Comment: With the data you provide in your question is not possible to know what's going on.

Comment: What is this: `...` ??

Comment: Where is that output coming from? You haven't shown the relevant code so we can't say. You need to find the command printing that output and modify/silence it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided in your question doesn't have any problem:

```
$ cat scripta
. ./scriptb
echo $toto

$ cat scriptb 
export toto="hello!"

$ ./scripta 
hello!
```